# How can I call variable in env section in reuse workflow in github action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

This is my github action workflow, and I trie to call variable in **env:** section and use it in the job below

```
name: Docker-image-build-push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "dev"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "dev"

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  FULL_REPOSITORY: ${{ github.repository }}
  TAG: dev

jobs:
  build-and-push-docker-images:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-push-docker-image-template.yaml
    with:
      full_repository: ${{ env.FULL_REPOSITORY }}
      registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
      tags: ${{ env.TAG }}
    secrets:
      actor: ${{ github.actor }}
      token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

How can I call variable in **env:** section and its value in job

I have tried this

```
name: Docker-image-build-push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "dev"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "dev"

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  FULL_REPOSITORY: ${{ github.repository }}
  TAG: dev

jobs:
  build-and-push-docker-images:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-push-docker-image-template.yaml
    with:
      full_repository: $FULL_REPOSITORY
      registry: $REGISTRY
      tags: $TAG
    secrets:
      actor: ${{ github.actor }}
      token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Also, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations.